# Use react-hooks inside embedded react in a vue app

Tags: reactjs, vue.js

Issue : App throwing invalid use to `react-hook`

```
react.development.js?eead:209 Warning: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
printWarning @ react.development.js?eead:209
error @ react.development.js?eead:183
resolveDispatcher @ react.development.js?eead:1592
useState @ react.development.js?eead:1621
UserAnalytics @ UserAnalytics.tsx?e9dd:10
renderWithHooks @ react-dom.development.js?61bb:16305
mountIndeterminateComponent @ react-dom.development.js?61bb:20074
beginWork @ react-dom.development.js?61bb:21587
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js?61bb:4164
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js?61bb:4213
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js?61bb:4277
beginWork$1 @ react-dom.development.js?61bb:27451
performUnitOfWork @ react-dom.development.js?61bb:26560
workLoopSync @ react-dom.development.js?61bb:26466
renderRootSync @ react-dom.development.js?61bb:26434
performConcurrentWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js?61bb:25738
workLoop @ scheduler.development.js?3069:266
flushWork @ scheduler.development.js?3069:239
performWorkUntilDeadline @ scheduler.development.js?3069:533
react.development.js?eead:1622 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useState')
    at useState (react.development.js?eead:1622:1)
    at UserAnalytics (UserAnalytics.tsx?e9dd:10:1)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js?61bb:16305:1)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js?61bb:20074:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js?61bb:21587:1)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js?61bb:4164:1)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js?61bb:4213:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js?61bb:4277:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js?61bb:27451:1)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js?61bb:26560:1)
```

Set-up : I am trying to migrate my `vue-2` app to `react`. I have created a `react-migration` folder inside my `vue` app. App is booted via `vue-cli` which has a `react-wrapper` which in turn loads the `react-component`. I am able to load the component but for some reason not able to run the hooks.

`react` package.json
[image: react package.json]

`vue` package.json
[image: vue package.json]

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function Test() {
  // Declare a new state variable, which we'll call "count"
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  return (
    <>
      <p>You clicked {count} times</p>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>
        Click me
      </button>
    </>
  );
}

export default Test;
```

Tried : [embedded react-hook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72166957/how-to-use-react-hooks-inside-embedded-react)

Now I have used the same code by creating a new react app which runs fine.

I believe it's because the app is booted via vue?

`ReactWrapper.vue`

```
<template>
    <div ref="container" /> 
 </template>  
 <script> 
 import { createElement } from "react"; 
 import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";  
 export default {
    inheritAttrs: false,
    props: {
      component: {
        type: Function,
        required: true,
      },
    },
    data() {
      return {
        reactRoot: null,
      };
    },
    watch: {
      $attrs: {
        deep: true,
        handler() {
          this.updateReactComponent();
        },
      },
    },
    mounted() {
      this.reactRoot = createRoot(this.$refs.container);     
      this.updateReactComponent();
    },
    destroyed() {
      this.reactRoot.unmount();
    },
    methods: {
      updateReactComponent() {
        this.reactRoot.render(createElement(this.component, this.$attrs));
      },
    },
  };
  </script>
```

`TestReact.vue`

```
<template>
    <react-wrapper :component="ReactComponent" />
</template>

<script>
// import { LoginComponent } from "../react-migration/src/components/login/LoginComponent";
import UserAnalytics from "../react-migration/src/components/user-analytics/UserAnalytics";

export default {
    name: "TestReact",
    computed: {
        ReactComponent() {
            return UserAnalytics;
        },
    },
};
</script>

<style></style>
```

Comment: "react-wrapper" - what is it? "which in turn loads the react-component" - how? It's unknown what you're doing exactly. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors .

Comment: It's supposed to be workable the way you did it, the problem is not reproducible. Try to reinstall the deps, make sure there's no nested dupe `react` in node_modules, make sure that installed react-dom and react versions really match, `^` doesn't guarantee that, the reasons why you get this error are basically what it describes.

Comment: I've hit a similar but different problem.  I'm using the exact same wrapper and most of my hooks are working, but trying to use something like react-router or i18next results in the error `Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue by matching my `node` version with `react's`.
Upgraded `v14.17.4` to `v14.17.6`